# Build a local Maven project and use it as a dependency

Tags: java, maven

I work on a project with several separatd modules.

- `project-1-team-1`

  - pom.xml
- `project-2-team-1`

  - pom.xml
- `project-3-team-1`

  - pom.xml

..

Is there any way to add a module and use it as an embedded library in `project-1` and `project-2` with a Maven build at each time?

- `shared-lib`

  - pom.xml
- `project-1-team-1` ---references-as-dependency---> `shared-lib`

  - pom.xml
- `project-2-team-1` ---references-as-dependency---> `shared-lib`

  - pom.xml
- `project-3-team-1`

  - pom.xml

I mean, when I build `project-1` or `project-2`, `shared-lib` must be built too (automatically) and get embedded as a new jar `project-1` or `project-2`?

In other words, `mvn package` on `project-1` means `mvn package` on `project-1` and `shared-lib`.

Edit:
I don't have access to a private/corporate repository and can not change the structure of the projects.

Comment: If you have the code `shared-lib` locally, just run `mvn install` on it. This will install that project in your local repository. From there on, you are free to reference it in other (local) projects.

Comment: I tried this option, but I want to get this feature automatically if someone updates the `shared-library` after pulling new commits.

Comment: I would suggest to create a multi module build of it...

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no “automatic” way to do this, the project will need to be rebuilt after each bunch of commits and then installed into your local repo again as such I would suggest @Turing85 is correct.  To my knowledge the closest to automatic you can get is a CI tool which pulls from your source repo, in which case you will need a shared repo, I have used Nexus for this in the past.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you go with @Gavin's suggestion, you would either need to override artifacts in the maven repository or update the version of the dependency in the project using `shared-libs`.

Comment: @khmarbaise a multi-module project may work, but there would be, at least to my mind a large degree of couple especially if the shared module were to be used in another project unrelated to the one described in the post. Having made extensive use of multi-module poms in the past I now feel they are generally a mistake or have a limited number of use-cases.  Just my opinion of course and if they work for you that’s all for the good 

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `mvn clean install -pl project-1-team-1 -am`

Comment: This will not work if `shared-libs` is not in the reactor (which it is not).